# Error: expression cannot be used as function - operator()

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, dynamic-arrays

I'm building a wrapper class for a single pointer that acts as a TwoD array.
I have an overloaded operator() for returning a value from the array.
I want to be able to use operator() for accessing array values of the form **arr(r,c)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class TwoDArray
{
    private:
        T * arr;
        int rows, columns, size;
        int getIndex(int r, int c)
        {
            int index = (r*columns) + c;
            return index;
        }
    public:
        /*Constructor*/
        TwoDArray(int r = 1, int c = 1) : rows(r), columns(c)
        {
            if(r > 0 && c > 0)
            {
                size = rows*columns;
                arr = new T [size];
                memset(arr, 0, sizeof(int)*size);
            }

            else
            {
                arr = NULL;
            }
        }

        void setAtIndex(int r, int c, T value)
        {
            int index = getIndex(r, c);
            arr[index] = value;
        }

        //lvalue - has the effect obj(r,c);
        T& operator()(unsigned int r, unsigned int c)
        {
            if(r >= rows || c >= columns)
            {
                cerr<<"Unable to locate memory\n";
                exit(0);
            }
            return arr[getIndex(r,c)];
        }

        //rvalue - has the effect obj(r,c);
        const T& operator()(unsigned int r, unsigned int c) const
        {
            if(r >= rows || c >= columns)
            {
                cerr<<"Unable to locate memory\n";
                exit(0);
            }
            return arr[getIndex(r,c)];
        }

        void displayTwoD() const
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
                {
                    cout<<this->arr(i,j);
                }
                cout<<"\n";
            }
        }

        /*Destructor*/
        ~TwoDArray()
        {
            if(arr != NULL)
                delete arr;
            arr = NULL;
        }
};

int main()
{
    TwoDArray <int> tda(5,5);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
        {
            tda.setAtIndex(i,j, (i+1)*2);
        }
    }

    tda.displayTwoD();
    return 0;
}
```

I get the error:

```
G:\DS>g++ checkError.cpp
checkError.cpp: In instantiation of 'void TwoDArray<T>::displayTwoD() const [with T = int]':
checkError.cpp:95:18:   required from here
checkError.cpp:68:10: error: expression cannot be used as a function
      cout<<this->arr(i,j);
```

when I use

```
cout<<arr(i,j);
```

anywhere in the code. I want to know why this happens and how to solve it.

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: G:\DS>g++ TwoDArray.cpp

TwoDArray.cpp: In instantiation of 'void TwoDArray<T>::displayTwoD() const [with T = int]':

TwoDArray.cpp:159:18:   required from here

TwoDArray.cpp:119:10: error: expression cannot be used as a function
      cout<<this->arr(i,j);

Comment: Present your [MCVE].

Comment: By the way I'm confused about your comments. Did you really mean "lvalue" and "rvalue" there?

Comment: That's what my instructor told the functions would do..

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Now I see what you want to do. You want to call the operator() from within a member function. You can do this by de-referencing "this":

```
(*this)(i,j)
```

Old answer, but made no sense:

TwoDArray::arr is a pointer, you need to de-reference it: (*arr)(i,j)

Comment: this removes the error, however, the problem still remains.I still can't use the operator() on the pointer. It could be because the operator doesn't belong to the arr object, instead it belongs to objects of class TwoDArray.
But then, how will I invoke the same method within the TwoDArray class?

Comment: Same idea: (*this)(i,j)

Comment: *(this)(i,j) doesn't work.. Gets me back to the old error

Comment: The star needs to be inside the parentheses.